# How to set the page to small printable format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my web page i will have content in top left with 3 inches width and 4 inches height data. I want to print that to small page like a train ticket or bus ticket. How can i convert that to small printable format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate print stylesheet like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Change the text to the required size inside this stylesheet and when the user prints, it will be that size. =)